# How can i convert type IPython.core.display.Image to base64 string using tempfile?

Tags: python, image, base64, random-forest, graphviz

I am trying to visualize a Decision Tree from a Random Forest Classifier.
However the type of the image that is being generated is of the type `IPython.core.display.Image` I wish to convert this into a base64 string by using the tempfile library

```
import tempfile
import base64
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model.best_estimator_[0], out_file=None, 
                                feature_names=X_train.columns,  
                                class_names=unique_target)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  

# Show graph
image= Image(graph.create_png())

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix=".png") as tmpfile:
    fig = image.get_figure()

"AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'get_figure'"

type(image)
Out[32]: IPython.core.display.Image
```

I am getting the error as:

> "AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'get_figure'"

I am kind of lost on how to
convert this into a base64 without explicitly saving the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked. I tried with a friend for a couple of hours.

```
import base64
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model.best_estimator_[0], out_file=None, 
                                feature_names=X_train.columns,  
                                class_names=unique_target)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  


image= Image(graph.create_png())
```

```
Encoded_Image=str(base64.b64encode(image.data)) ##That's the line you add before you save it as an Encoded String
```

There is no need to add the tempfile part of the code.